# Volkswagen Golf MK4 - Oil temperature sensor coding out

Tags: oil, golf, sensor, dtc, vw

I have a Volkswagen Golf MK4 TDI 85kw (AJM). After driving for a while  and stopping, when I turn the ignition on I get an "Oil sensor workshop"  message. After connecting VCDS I got this fault:

> 00534 -  Engine Oil Temperature Sensor (G8)
>
> 27-00 -  Implausible Signal

As far as I know its the same sensor for the oil level too.  I've done some research and I found that these sensors can be disabled.  On some forums, I found that you need to re-code the instrument cluster module and set it to 17402 or 17432 but neither of these works for me.  The first one is just an invalid option and the second one was coded with no success.  I'm wondering if there are any other ways of doing that? Or perhaps I did something wrong?

Also it would be nice to hear what are the possible causes of getting this exact fault as it appears only when the car is driven for a while and the engine is hot.

*Note: I used VCDS-lite registered version for connecting to my car.

**UPDATE**

I've tried to disconnect the connector from the sensor. I actually expected it to show me "Oil sensor workshop" message all the time but at the beginning it looked like everything is fine no message on the dash. And after driving for a while the fault appeared as with the connector plugged in.

**Detailed information needed about theese questions**

1. Is there any way of programming out this sensor?
2. Is there any way of fooling a computer about this sensor using resistors or something like that and how?
3. As there are 3 wires coming to that sensor, how does it work? what's the purpose of each wire, and if data used by the computer is the resistance of of specific sensor's connections whats the normal resistance between each of them?
4. Is this sensor used to only warn a driver about the issues with the oil level or temperature or is it that this data also used by the main computer and does it affects how the engine runs? What exactly is affected by it?

Comment: This is a $15 sensor. Why not just replace it?

Comment: I should add, disabling this may not have any positive benefit and could cause a lot of issues. From what I understand about these particular diesel engines, is this sensor affects many aspects of how your engine runs especially at Idle.

Comment: Does the error reappear if reset? Implausible signal often means a dirty or loose contact/connector or broken wire or in a much rarer case a broken sensor. You should check for an actual fault, though. That's what the sensor is there to warn you about!

Comment: I have replaced this sensor for 3 times already 2 of which it was leaking oil. and this sensor is something like 80$ plus the oil as you need to drain it out.   And as far as I know it doesn't affect how the engine runs as I had a faulty one which didn't work at all. and I believe it is just used to warn about low oil level (which I check pretty often manually) and as the fault says something about the temperature maybe.

Comment: And yes the fault reappears when cleared

Comment: Replacing sensors is part of VW owning experience. Enjoy!

Comment: If replacing the part is not fixing the error _and_ the error appears when the part is unplugged (?!) then that sensor is obviously not the problem, right?  There should be an electrical test (resistance, contact closure, something) that you can use to test the sensor rather than replace it.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than reprogram the ECU to ignore the sensor (which could then cause problems in the event there was a problem with your engine oil), why not simply replace the sensor.  I'm sure it will be an inexpensive part when compared to the potential damage running with an unreported oil fault could cause.

Also, as you say you've checked and replaced the sensor several times, check that condition of the loom and connectors.

Comment: The OP specifically mentions that the sensor has been replaced several times already.

Comment: Oh yes, I've just seen that in the comments.  The fact that two of the replacement sensors were leaking oil is worrying too.  Surprising if they were genuine replacements purchased from VW and fitted following the correct procedure.  However, I stick by my position that running without a sensor or the sensor disabled could lead to significant engine damage in an oil failure situation.  I'd be tempted, for piece of mind, to connect some mechanical gauges and check that the engine is acutally behaving.  VW oil pickup pipes are notorious for fouling their gause strainers in the sump.

Answer (score 1):

The Oil Sensor works with temperature or ultra sonic measurement. 
The temperature style sensor heats itself up above your current oil temperature to then be cooled by the surrounding oil. The time needed for cooling gives information about the oil level. High level fast cooldown, low level slow cooldown.

A lot of times issues relate to broken wires - temperature measurement via resistance + broken wires == high resistance.

This (German) article is exactly your Sensor if I am not mistaken: 
http://www.t4-wiki.de/wiki/Geber_G266_%28%C3%96lstand/%C3%96ltemperatur%29

Most of the time the sensor input is fed more or less directly into the ECU or any connector nearby. Checking for resistance within the cable gives you a clue about what happens here. See image in article.

The Pins 1 and 2 connect to Clamps 15 and 31 whereas Pin 3 is the signal to the ECU.

**One more thing:** 
The warning should be reset when opening and closing the hood. If not, check the switch in the hood. http://www.t4-wiki.de/wiki/Schalter_F266_%28Motorhaube%29

Even though I believe it is not the sensor, in case you need a new one: the Ford Sensors  1 119 169 and USAYM216C624AA are only half as expensive and said to be compatible.